# Save excel invoice as xlsm and pdf based on 2 cell values and then print...A Solution

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

My aim- to have a button on an excel invoice that once pressed will print the invoice, save to xlsm, save to pdf (both saves to have automatic name taken from two cells, invoice no. and customer name) then close down the workbook.

I have searched low and high for an answer to this but have only found help in the separate elements.

The cells needed for the file name are C18 and A7.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: thanks for the edit, it's actually an answer to my own question which I could not find an answer to...I found a solution by searching different elements of the problem. Just wanted to share it so anyone else with the same problem could find it easily.

Comment: Then you should ask a proper question first and post your answer as answer to your question. Read also [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking).

Comment: thanks for the info, I'm new here so will follow that next time!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, no problem to be new here ;) You can edit your question into a good question ([ask]) and then post what you already have as an answer. You really should change that into a question+answer because if you don't I assume this question will be closed down by the community soon. This site is different from a forum it is based on a question+answer schema.

Comment: Thanks Peh, edited question and posted answer below

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Peh for teaching me proper etiquette. Here is the answer to my question-

Here's the code- (please read comments marked with ' to understand what each bit does)

```
Sub SaveandPrint() 'this is the macro's name

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Path As String

    ActiveSheet.PrintOut 'this bit prints the sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Path = "C:\add\your\file\destination\here" 'Change the directory path here where you want to save the file
    FileName = Range("C18").Value & " " & Range("A7").Value & ".xlsm" 'Change extension here for different excel formats.
    'Also, change range cell values to select different cell value for naming
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled 'Change the format here which matches with the extension above. 'Choose from the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr.../ff198017.aspx

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Dim fName As String 'this is the saving to pdf bit
    fName = Range("C18").Value & " " & Range("A7").Value 'again, change cells to C18 and A7 to the ones you want to name file

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    "C:\add\your\file\destination\here" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _ 'change destination folder 
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close 'closes the workbook

End Sub
```

Hope this helps and save some lots of time, took me bloody ages to wrap my head round it and implement it!

Comment: Looks better. Now your last step should be to [mark your own answer as solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so everyone sees that the question is solved.

Comment: Cheers, says I have to wait 2 days to accept as a solution, so will come back. Muchos Gracias Peh!